# Как правильно сокращать предложение?

Tags: цитирование

Лопатин:

1. § 141. Если цитата приводится не полностью, то пропуск обозначается многоточием (в начале цитаты, в середине или в конце):

б) «Биография героини... записана в одной из моих записных книжек», — пишет в одном из своих писем из Комарова А. Ахматова;

(Оригинал:

Биография героини (полу-Ольга, – полу-Т. Вечеслова) записана в одной из моих записных книжек – там балетная школа (Т.В.), полонез с Нижинским, Дягилев, Париж, Москва – балаганы, художник, la danse russe в Царскосельском дворце и т. д. Всего этого Поэма не захотела.)

2. § 144. При сокращении цитаты, уже имеющей многоточия, выполняющие те или иные свойственные им функции, многоточие, поставленное автором, цитирующим текст, указывающее на сокращение цитаты, заключается в угловые скобки: 
   В дневнике Л. Н. Толстого читаем:

«Она не может отречься от своего чувства <...>. У нее, как у всех женщин, первенствует чувство, и всякое изменение происходит, может быть, независимо от разума, в чувстве... Может быть, Таня права, что это само собой понемногу пройдет <...>».

(Оригинал:

«Она не может отречься от своего чувства, не может разумом влиять на чувства. У нее, как у всех женщин, первенствует чувство, и всякое изменение происходит, может быть, независимо от разума, в чувстве... Может быть, Таня права, что это само собой понемногу пройдет своим особенным, непонятным мне женским путем».)

3. § 163. Возможны варианты в расстановке знаков при использовании точки с запятой и тире, точки с запятой и двоеточия. В каждом конкретном случае варианты отличаются смысловыми оттенками. Ср.: Деревья тут валятся, и вода, как испуганная, бросается в сторону; там она опять подмывает деревья (Пришв.). — Деревья тут валятся, и вода, как испуганная, бросается в сторону — там она опять подмывает деревья (точка с запятой указывает на равнозначность частей предложения, тире подчеркивает смысловую зависимость последней части от предыдущей); Вскоре дорога наша определилась, мы едем по
   правому высокому берегу реки; сквозь неодетые лиственные и разные хвойные деревья виднеется внизу широкая долина Тоймы (Пришв.). — Мы едем по правому высокому берегу реки: сквозь <...> деревья виднеется внизу <...> долина Тоймы (двоеточие подчеркивает пояснительный характер последней части предложения).

Вопросы:

А) Почему в § 141 в конце сокращенной цитаты нет многоточия?

Б) Почему в § 163 при сокращении цитаты используются угловые скобки, хотя в оригинале нет многоточия?

В) Почему в оригинале точка с запятой после "реки", а при сокращении - двоеточие?

Answer (score 1):

A) Многоточие в конце ставится, если представлен сокращённый текст (а не просто мысль из текста) — то есть соблюдается вся его структура. Такие сокращения важны на данном сайте, где очень важна структура предложения. Но ведь можно процитировать и два слова — тогда структура будет неважна и не будут использовать два многоточия. Особенно нужно многоточие в конце, если предложение оборвано (конец неустойчивый), как это в § 144. А если конец цитаты устойчивый, как в § 141, и важна не структура текста, а мысль, то в конце часто не ставят многоточие. Такое обычно когда предложение после цитаты продолжается — в прямой речи или когда цитата комментируется.

Б) Допустимо использовать угловые скобки, если хочется предупредить то, что кто-то воспримет многоточие как оригинальное.

B) Это к сокращению никак не относится: оно никак не влияет на оригинальную пунктуацию. Видимо, есть разные редакции этого предложения.